# IBM RS/6000 Token Ring ISA card not operational

Tags: ibm, network

After solving [a configuration challenge](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27755/ibm-rs-6000-token-ring-isa-card-fails-configuration/27757), the ISA Token Ring adapter in my RS/6000 is still not connected to the ring.

Extract from `errpt -a`:

```
LABEL:          NONE
IDENTIFIER:     0118D2D0

Date/Time:       Sat Sep 30 10:20:15 
Sequence Number: 4348
Machine Id:      005D8D264C00
Node Id:         r390
Class:           U
Type:            NONE
Resource Name:   tok0
Resource Class:  adapter
Resource Type:   tokenring
Location:        01-01
VPD:             
        Displayable Message.........ISA Token Ring
```

Output of `tokstat tok0`, which takes several seconds to return:

```
tokstat: 0909-004 Unable to get statistics on device tok0, errno = 69
```

When I run the test routine of the adapter in SMS, the adapter can be 'opened' successfully, I see the MAU lobe become active.

AIX is not able to achieve the same, even though the adapter is reported to be 'available'.

```
tok0 Available 01-01 IBM 16/4 PowerPC Token-Ring Adapter (isa)
```

I cannot find any useful information in regards to the output of `errpt` or `tokstat`.

The LEDs on the card blink in pattern 'green, green, amber, off`.

What can I do to understand why AIX struggles to use the adapter?

EDIT:

Some progress:

```
# tokstat tok0
-------------------------------------------------------------
TOKEN-RING STATISTICS (tok0) :
Device Type: Token-Ring IBM ISA Adapter
Hardware Address: 08:00:5a:d2:85:45
Elapsed Time: 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 5 seconds

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 0
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 0
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 0
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 1

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 0
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Receive Congestion Errors: 0
Current SW Transmit Queue Length: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 1

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0                             Lobe Wire Faults: 0
Abort Errors: 0                               AC Errors: 0
Burst Errors: 0                               Frame Copy Errors: 0
Frequency Errors: 0                           Hard Errors: 0
Internal Errors: 0                            Line Errors: 0
Lost Frame Errors: 0                          Only Station: 0
Token Errors: 0                               Remove Received: 0
Ring Recovered: 0                             Signal Loss Errors: 0
Soft Errors: 0                                Transmit Beacon Errors: 0
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex 16 Mbps
```

An incorrect setting apparently prevented communication with the card.

Now there are no more errors reported by `errpt` and `tokstat` reports something, though the adapter isn't opened permanently. `tokstat` opens it briefly, though it closes again immediately afterwards.

What needs to happen to make the adapter be open continuously?